# Find array keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

In PHP I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array[0]['width'] = '100';
$array[0]['height'] = '200';
$array[2]['width'] = '150';
$array[2]['height'] = '250';
```

- I don't know how many items there are in the array.
- Some items can be deleted which explains the missing [1] key.

I want to add a new item after this, like this:

```
$array[]['width'] = '300';
$array[]['height'] = '500';
```

However the code above don't work, because it adds a new key for each row. It should be the same for the two rows above. A clever way to solve it?

An alternative solution would be to find the last key. I failed trying the 'end' function.

Comment: just want to add note: adding value to $array[] is equal to create new key. You can use several solution below to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind it losing those keys, you could easily fix the problem by re-indexing.

```
$array = array_values($array);
$i = count($array);
$array[$i]['width'] = '300';
$array[$i]['height'] = '500';
```

However, if you don't want to do this, you could also use this:

```
$array[] = array(
    'width' => '300',
    'height' => '500'
);
```

Which will create a new array and inserts it as a second dimension.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to do this is:

```
$array[] = array(
  'width' => 200,
  'height' => 500,
);
```

because you're actually adding a new array to `$array`.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
$array[] = array("width" => "300", "height" => "500");
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, just for completeness and obviousness, use a temporary array:

```
$t=array();
$t['width']='300';
$t['height']='500';
```

And then add it to the main array:

```
$array[]=$t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, useful when you cannot add both values in a single statement:

```
$a = array();
$array[] &= $a; // Append a reference to the array, instead of a copy

$a['width'] = '300';
$a['height'] = '500';
```

But you can also retrieve the last key in the array:

```
$array[]['width'] = '300';

end($array); // Make sure the internal array pointer is at the last item
$key = key($array);  // Get the key of the last item

$array[$key]['height'] = 300;
```

Comment: I didn't even realise you could assign a reference in PHP. Thanks.